# Button with double action (tap & long press) in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, long-press

Is it possible in SwiftUI to set a button with an action on tap and a different action on long press ?

I have tried this:

```
Button(action: {
    self.handleButtonTap()
})
{
    Text("My nice button")
        .foregroundColor(.primary)
}
.onLongPressGesture {
    print("Long pressed!")
}
```

or instead of:

```
.onLongPressGesture {
    print("Long pressed!")
}
```

using this:

```
.gesture(longPress)
```

where long press is something like:

```
var longPress: some Gesture {
  ....
}
```

But nothing seems to work.
At best I have been able to attach the long press gesture to the Text of the button, but even in that case the normal tap cease to work.

Any good advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if this works for you:

```
Button("Button") {
    print("tapped")
}
.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
    print("long pressed")
})
```

Please note that tap action is executed after every long press in the above code. You can handle this with a simple Bool.

Comment: Yes, it works. As you mention, it can be handled with a boolean.

Comment: One more detail, in some cases; the boolean work around is not needed because the main action is just not called. Like if you bring up another view in the long press action.

Comment: This is a more compact solution, but @Alexander-Sandberg solution is better if you want to avoid having the button long press call both tap and long press.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another solution that doesn't trigger the regular tap action after every long press.

```
Button("Button") {
    // No tap action here
}
.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
    print("Long-pressed")
})
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
    print("Tapped")
})
```

I learned about this in this blog post: [Supporting Both Tap and Long Press on a Button in SwiftUI](https://steipete.com/posts/supporting-both-tap-and-longpress-on-button-in-swiftui/)

**Note:** This might not work as expected with Catalyst, which you can learn more about in the blog post above.

Comment: @Michel This might be a better solution if you're having issues with the boolean workaround.

Comment: IMO this is a great solution.

Comment: The sample code from the linked blog post answered the question for me. Thank you!